# How can I change the boot.ini file on a number of machine by script?

Tags: windows, group-policy

How can I change the boot.ini file on a group of client PCs at the same time by using something such as a group policy?

Answer (score 2):

Write a .bat file that pulls a boot.ini through a share?

1. Create your new boot.ini
2. Create a share folder
3. Create a .bat file that looks like ...

   ```
   @echo off
   net use Z: \\ComputerName\ShareName /persistent:no
   copy Z:\boot.ini C:\ /Y
   ```

Then make add it to the login scripts GPO.

This isn't perfect. As it will run every time a user logs in ...

[Net Use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: old school but nice answer :)

Comment: If this works, that means your users have "Administrator" rights, and that's not the right way to be doing things. You should be doing this in a "Startup Script", and you don't need the "drive" "mapping"-- you can copy from a UNC path just fine.